# Dictionary cannot be use to set metadata whe using robot.run?

Tags: robotframework

When I try to use a dictionary to setup `--metadata` on `robot.run` it only displays the keys of the dictionary, not the actual values.

```
meta = {'version':"2.1", 'name':"MY_NAME"} 
robot.run(my_suite.path, metadata=meta)
```

But on  the final report the values are not reported only the keys of the dictionary are being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing it as a list of `key:value` pairs:

```
meta = ['version:2.1', 'name:MY_NAME']
robot.run(my_suite.path, metadata=meta)
```

Comment: Yes in that way it works !! seems like by definition the metadata should be sent as a list

[settings.py](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/conf/settings.py#L37)

Comment: Yep, it's a bit complicated - parsed as a list of key:value pairs in the runner, and in the same time, a [dict in the model](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1/autodoc/robot.model.html#robot.model.testsuite.TestSuite.metadata). Glad it works for you.